# Extending a $\sigma$-weakly continuous map: Takesaki IV.5.13

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, topological-vector-spaces

Consider the following fragment from chapter IV in Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebra I":

[image]

Why is the boxed line true? Takesaki argues that
$$\theta_0: \mathscr{M}_1\otimes_{\operatorname{min}} \mathscr{M}_2 \to \mathscr{N}_1\otimes_{\operatorname{min}} \mathscr{N}_2: m_1 \otimes m_2 \mapsto \theta_1(m_1)\otimes \theta_2(m_2)$$
is $\sigma$-weakly continuous, but why does this ensure that the map $\theta_0$ extends to a $\sigma$-weakly continuous map on the von Neumann tensor products? I guess some general fact about topological vector spaces is invoked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general setup in topological spaces would be the following: given topological spaces $X,Y$ and a dense $X_0\subseteq X$ with $T:X_0\rightarrow Y$ continuous (for the subspace topology on $X_0$) we can extend $T$ by continuity to $X$.  This is of course *not true* (exercise to the reader to find a counter-example for e.g. $X_0=(0,1), X=[0,1]$).

A true statement can be fashioned by using the theory of [Uniform Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space), [Uniform Continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Uniform_continuity) and [Completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Completeness).  I believe that then a general statement could be formulated and proved for topological vector spaces.

However, in this case, I think there are *some missing details* in Takesaki's proof, and I would prefer to give a different approach.

---

The way I would think about this problem is to use some Banach space theory.  The general setup is to let $E,F$ be Banach spaces, let $E_0\subseteq E^*$ be a weak$^*$-dense subspace, and let $T_0:E_0\rightarrow F^*$ be bounded, linear, and weak$^*$-continuous.  We claim we can extend $T_0$ to $T:E^*\rightarrow F^*$ a weak$^*$-continuous bounded linear map.

In fact, Takesaki proves something different.  We can consider the Banach space adjoint (here I follow Takesaki's notation) ${}^t T_0:F^{**}\rightarrow E_0^*$, consider $F$ as a subspace of $F^{**}$ and so ask about ${}^t T_0(F) \subseteq E_0^*$.

Also each member of $E$ induces a functional on $E_0$, and by Hahn-Banach, weak$^*$-density of $E_0$ in $E^*$ implies that the resulting map $E\rightarrow E_0^*$ is at least injective.  Takesaki shows that ${}^t T_0(F) \subseteq E$.  So there is a linear map $S:F\rightarrow E$ making the following commute:
$$ \require{AMScd}\begin{CD} F^{**} @>{{}^t T_0}>> E_0^* \\
@AAA @AAA \\
F @>{S}>> E \end{CD} $$
Explicitly, given $\omega\in F$ and $x\in E_0\subseteq E^*$,
$$ \langle x, S(\omega) \rangle_{E^*,E} =
\langle {}^t T_0(\omega), x \rangle_{E_0^*, E_0}
= \langle T_0(x), \omega \rangle_{F^*,F}. $$
In general, I *see no reason why $S$ need be bounded*.  Kaplansky density comes to the rescue, because $M_1 \otimes_{\min} M_2$ is a weak$^*$-dense $C^*$-subalgebra of $M_1 \overline\otimes M_2$, and so the unit ball is dense.  Abstractly, this means we may add the additional hypothesis that the unit ball of $E_0$ is weak$^*$-dense in the unit ball of $E^*$.  Equivalently (by Hahn-Banach again) $E_0$ *norms* $E$.  So
\begin{align*}
\|S(\omega)\| &= \sup \{ |\langle x,S(\omega)\rangle| : x\in E_0, \|x\|\leq 1 \} \\
&= \sup \{ |\langle T_0(x), \omega \rangle| : x\in E_0, \|x\|\leq 1 \} \\
&\leq \|T_0\| \|\omega\|.
\end{align*}
Thus $S$ is bounded, with $\|S\| \leq \|T_0\|$.

Now set $T = {}^t S_0 : E^*\rightarrow F^*$ and it's an easy exercise to show that $T$ extends $T_0$; clearly $T$ is weak$^*$-continuous as it's a Banach space adjoint.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't think harder about how your answer relates to OP's question when I wrote my answer. I've deleted mine in favor of this one, which is also earlier. Let me just comment that imho, the "correct way" to look at this question is identifying the transpose of (the norm-continuous extension) of $^t\theta$ being exactly what we are looking for, instead of struggling to extend directly by $\sigma$-weak continuity, which seems to be the key idea here, too.

Comment: Regarding the continuous extension. The most general result (which I think is due to Bourbaki) that I know is the following: let $X$, $Y$ be topological spaces, suppose $Y$ is Hausdorff and regular, $A$ is a dense subspace of $X$, $f : A \to Y$ is continuous. For each $x \in X$, let $\mathfrak{F}_x$ denote the trace of the filter of neighborhoods of $x$ on $A$. Then $f$ can be extended to a continuous map $F: X \to Y$ if and only if the filter basis $f_*(\mathfrak{F}_x)$ converges in $Y$ for each $x \in X$.

Comment: ...The proof is not hard and makes very natural usage of the regularity of $Y$ in the sense that closed neighborhoods of any point form a fundamental system (the Hausdorff condition is only used to make sure the limit is unique once exists). A complete proof can be found in Bourbaki's book on general topology (section I.8.5, theorem 1). All continuous extension results that I've encountered, be it in the context topological groups/vector spaces, uniform spaces, etc., are special cases of this one.

Comment: @HuaWang Why don't you leave your answer? I agree that it is the more natural approach, though I wanted to address the OP directly, and try to indicate where things can go wrong in more general settings. In particular, it seems to me vital that one can use Kaplansky Density here.

Comment: @MatthewDaws Thanks for the beautifu; answer! One can also prove this fact from Takesaki's book using Stinespring's decomposition theorem (in very much the same way we show that minimal tensor product maps between c.p. maps make sense)!